# why is the 'input' event firing on page refresh in IE for textarea and input (non-text)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Can someone advise why the 'input' event is firing when a form is refreshed.

It doesn't do it on normal text inputs, but it is for textarea and input[type=number]

Basically I have a textarea with required, and due to IE11 not applying pseudo classes correctly, I have had to bind events to call the validation code and manually apply the valid/invalid classes.

```
$('[required]').on('input',function(){ checkValid(this);}); 

function checkValid(ele)
{

if(ele.validity.valid)
{   
    $(ele).removeClass('invalid'); 
    $(ele).addClass('valid'); 
}
else
{ 
    $(ele).removeClass('valid'); 
    $(ele).addClass('invalid');        
}

}
```

If I refresh the page, the checkValid is running against the textarea and input[type=number] , but not normal inputs?

I have traced this to the 'input' event firing when the pages loads, but only after a refresh , not on initial page load.

Why is this and how do I stop it?

Thanks,
1DMF

**EDIT re comment**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// hide select list placeholders
$('select option:first').css('display','none');

// handle required fields as IE pseudo classes don't work properly   
$('select[required]').on('click',function(){ checkValid(this);});   
$('[required]').on('input',function(){ checkValid(this);});              
$('[required]').on('invalid',function(){ $(this).addClass('invalid'); });

// add JQuery UI tooltips
$('body').tooltip();

// now deal with FF and the fact refresh doesn't blank form fields!
$('[required]').each(function(){   
    if($(this).val() != '')
    {        
        checkValid(this);
    }            
});

});
```

Comment: wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){ //Your code });`